# forall in Context with Data constructor

Tags: haskell

I read on [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor#Data_constructor) about Data constructor and consider following:

> 2.1 Data constructors as first class values
>
> Data constructors are first class values in Haskell and actually have a type. For instance,
>   the type of the Left constructor of the Either data type is:
>
> `Left :: forall b a. a -> Either a b`
>
> As first class values, they may be passed
>   to functions, held in a list, be data elements of other algebraic data
>   types and so forth.

What does `forall` above mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types

Comment: While that wiki page gives an explanation of the meaning of `forall`, note well that the use of `forall` in the question does *not* construct an existential type as explained later on on in that page.  The only thing relevant to this question in that page is the "The `forall` keyword" section.  Just so you don't get confused.

Comment: From your profile it looks like you’re familiar with C#? `Left :: forall a b. a -> Either a b` is like `Either<A, B> Left<A, B> (A value)`. The Haskell `forall a b.` corresponds to the C# `<A, B>` in `Left<A, B>`—it defines the scope of the generic type parameters. Ordinarily this is implicit in Haskell, but you can (and sometimes have to) write it explicitly with the `ExplicitForall`, `ScopedTypeVariables`, or `RankNTypes` extensions. Likewise, if you’ve used C++, `forall a b.` is like `template<typename A, typename B>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`∀` quantor, aka `forall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification), is used implicitly in one way or another in *all* polymorphic Haskell signatures. For instance,

```
map :: ∀ a b . (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This is called *universal quantification*, and as you probably know it means that *for any* types `A` and `B` that you choose, `map` can be used as if it had the signature `(A -> B) -> [A] -> [B]`.

In Haskell98, this universal quantification with `∀ a b c ...` (all type variables that occur) right at the start of the signature was the *only* kind of polymorphism available, and it's still the most important. Hence this is implicit: when you see a signature with lowercase letters, the compiler knows that the signature really starts with `∀` over all these variables. So you can simply write

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

That also includes data constructors (which in expressions behave just like any other function. You'd normally write

```
Left :: a -> Either a b
```

but as I said, this is really just shorthand for

```
Left :: ∀ a b . a -> Either a b
```

or indeed

```
Left :: forall a b . a -> Either a b
```

In modern Haskell, it's sometimes necessary to use explicit quantors instead of the implicit ones. Namely,

- To “re-use” type variables from a top-level signature in a local signature. For instance, the following does not work:

  ```
  foldl :: (b->a->b) -> b -> [a] -> b
  foldl f = go
   where go :: b -> [a] -> b
         go acc [] = acc
         go acc (x:xs) = go (f acc x) xs
  ```

  The problem is that the local signature for `go`, due to the type variables therein, implies a new universal quantor, i.e. this really means

  ```
  foldl :: ∀ a b . (b->a->b) -> b -> [a] -> b
  foldl f = go
   where go :: ∀ a' b' . b' -> [a'] -> b'
         go acc [] = acc
         go acc (x:xs) = go (f acc x) xs  -- error: could not match a with a'
  ```

  However, `go` re-uses the same `f` that has already been bound in the `foldl f = ...` pattern, and that is *not* polymorphic (the types have already been fixed at that point), thus it's not possible to choose independent `a'` and `b'` type variables in `go`.
  The solution is to enable *scoped type variables* and then write explicitly

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
  foldl :: ∀ a b . (b->a->b) -> b -> [a] -> b
  foldl f = go
   where go :: b -> [a] -> b
         go acc [] = acc
         go acc (x:xs) = go (f acc x) xs
  ```

  Here, GHC knows that I *don't* want implicit quantors (because I've already written one explicitly). Thus the `a` and `b` in the signature of `go` are now the same type as used on the top level.
- To allow parameters to be polymorphic. This is called higher-rank polymorphism. The problem is similar to the one above: as I said, the locally-bound `f` is *not* polymorphic. (It usually can't be – you want to be able to use `foldl` with a function that's specific to one particular element type!)
  But in some application, a polymorphic function as and argument *is* what you want. For example, you might have a type that does arithmetic both in exact rational numbers and in quick-approximation floating point.

  ```
  data ApproxAndExact = ApproxAndExact Double Rational
  ```

  Now you want to perform operations on these numbers, but don't want to duplicate your code. So what you use is

  ```
  onBothReprs :: (∀ n . Fractional n => n -> n)
           -> ApproxAndExact -> ApproxAndExact
  onBothReprs f (ApproxAndExact approx exact)
            = ApproxAndExact (f approx) (f exact) -- note that both invocations
                                                  -- of f have different types!
  ```

  This can then be used like

  ```
  > obBothReprs (+273) 1e+16
  ApproxAndExact 1.0000000000000272e16 (10000000000000273 % 1)
  ```